# Reproducing "Computer composition with lines" in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, random

Folks,

I am trying to reproduce a famous computer art work, "Computer Composition with Lines", by A. Michael Noll, in R using ggplot.

Here is the original: https://collections.vam.ac.uk/item/O1193787/computer-composition-with-lines-photograph-noll-a-michael/

[image]

I made it to the point where I can create a circle of randomly black or white pixels, but I have a hard time in creating patterns similar to the ones used by Noll.

I can easily create a matrix of ones and zeroes, then cut away the parts that are out of a circle. But the pattern (I tried uniform, beta, normal...) is definitely too similar to white noise, while there is a structure in the randomness of the original work.

```
library(tidyverse)

# this generates the matrix
genData <- function(N) {

  # a N*N matrix of ones and zero according to a rounded beta draw
  df <- tibble(x = rep(seq(1,N), N),
         y = rep(seq(1,N), each = N),
         z = round(rbeta(N*N, 2, 1)))

  # centering on zero and cutting away all points outside of a circle
  df %>% 
    mutate(x = x-(N/2 + 1), y = y-(N/2 + 1)) %>% 
    filter(x^2 + y^2 < (N/2)^2)
}

#this plots the data
plotData <- function(df, color = "black"){
  df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x,y, fill = as.factor(z)))+
    geom_tile()+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c(color, "white"))+
    coord_equal()+
    theme_void()+
    theme(legend.position = "none")
}

#executing
genData(100) %>% 
  plotData()
```

Which results in:

[image]

I suppose the question boils down to **which random process can I use here**? I did not find any lead online.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this gets you a bit closer. I've also shortened the code by making use of `geom_segment`, which allows lengths to be drawn from a Poisson distribution.

It includes some logic to make the lines in the top section shorter.

If you try this with different random seeds you will probably find something you are happy with:

```r
draw_picture <- function(seed = 1, density = 1, length = 2, 
                         col = "black", bg = "gray90")
{
  set.seed(seed)
  
  x <- sample(100, 600 * density, TRUE) - 50
  y <- sample(100, 600 * density, TRUE) - 50
  ss <- which(sqrt(x^2 + y^2) < 50)
  x <- x[ss]
  y <- y[ss]
  orient <- sample(2, length(x), TRUE)
  
  lambda <- abs(ifelse(y > 0, length - 2/3 * length * abs(atan(y/x)), length))
  lens <- rpois(length(x), lambda) + 1
  end_x <- (orient %% 2) * lens + x
  end_y <- (orient - 1) * lens + y
  df <- data.frame(x, y, end_x, end_y)
  
  ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_segment(aes(xend = end_x, yend = end_y), color = col, size = 2) +
    coord_equal() +
    theme_void() +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = bg, color = NA))
}
```

So you can do:

```
draw_picture(8)
```

[image]

Or customize it with the parameters:

```r
draw_picture(2020, density = 0.9, length = 5, col = "#567AFF", bg = "#2345A0")
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks, it definitely gets closer. I had not thought of using geom_segment, I was thinking of some sort of game of life rules for the points so that segments would 'emerge'. I suppose the remaining (difficult, as far as I can see) is to have the point-like aritfacts at the top while the more segment like at the bottom. The random process must depend on the position in some way, but I did not figure out how. Thanks!

Comment: @PaoloCrosetto that’s possible too, though I wasn’t sure whether this was just random too. I’ll have another look when I get back to my computer.

Comment: couldn't you just make `length` a function of `x` and `y`?  e.g. the distance from `75,75`

Comment: @PaoloCrosetto see my update. This is a bit closer still.